# Suffering from Nothing

Tags: scala, types

How does the `A` turn to be `Nothing` in the process?

```
def seq2map[A](src: Seq[A]): Map[A, A] = {
    def pair = for {
        f <- src.headOption
        s <- src.headOption
    } yield (f, s)
    Stream continually pair takeWhile(_ isDefined) toMap
}
```

> error: Expression of type `Map[Nothing, Nothing]` doesn't conform to expected type `Map[A, A]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get

```
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that Option[(A, A)] <:< (T, U).
           Stream continually pair takeWhile(_ isDefined) toMap
                                                          ^
```

because

```
scala> val src = (1 to 10).toSeq
src: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala>     def pair = for {
     |         f <- src.headOption
     |         s <- src.headOption
     |     } yield (f, s)
pair: Option[(Int, Int)]
```

is not a pair, but an Option.

```
scala> (Stream continually pair takeWhile (_.isDefined)).flatten
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((1,1), ?)
```

is a stream of pairs.

Just waiting for the game to start.